# How do I have Symfony 2 ignore hidden files?

Tags: php, symfony

How do I have Symfony 2 ignore hidden files? If I edit my source tree, my Mac puts all kinds of .AppleDouble directories everywhere and I get errors like this (when running a command via CLI):

> The autoloader expected class
>   "Thing\CoreBundle\Command.AppleDouble\EnsureIndexesCommand" to
>   be defined in file
>   "/var/www/mysite.com/Symfony/app/../src/Thing/CoreBundle/Command/.AppleDouble/EnsureIndexesCommand.php".
>   The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or
>   namespace probably has a typo.

The .AppleDouble directory contains a file that ends in "Command.php" which is picked up by Symfony which thinks it's a valid command file when it's just serving some OSX purpose.

I see that there's an ignoreDotFiles option that is set on by default in the Finder.php constructor, but it apparently has no effect:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/7ab3fdeb8325d5a72c44dc73214c97f366a11c4c

I have to clean the source tree before I run every command which gets old and makes the Mac filesystem & Eclipse unstable since those hidden files are there for a reason.

Comment: Why would you be creating AppleDouble files... are you moving file back and forth within the workspace to other filesystems?

Comment: The source tree lives on a Linux box that I mount with my Mac. The Mac pollutes the Linux filesystem with the .AppleDouble files.